# Azure web app - extension, push and MySQL button cannot click/disabled

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I created a web app using Linux and PHP 7.2, build in East Asia.

I want to install Laravel and connect MySQL DB but it's disabling me to click in extension and other button.

I have searched but I can't find a solution to this problem, can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: Would you mind accept my reply as answer? Or you can post another reply to let others know and close this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extension option is not supported on Linux app.**

About connect to Azure SQL DB, here is the official tutorial you could follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-php-mysql-app?pivots=platform-linux

About install some module, the best way is writing the install command in workflow or `package.json` for installing automatically.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so, if i want to install laravel or connect database i need to type command in SSH?

Comment: Yes, we can do some installation on the SSH. Did you check the link I post? The first thing before publish is to make sure your project is working well locally.